# jQuery Templates: перенос шаблона из HTML в Javascript код

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос по  плагину jQuery Templates. Можно ли сам шаблон расположить не в HTML коде, а внутри JavaScript кода?

Например. В классическом варианте выглядит так:
     HTML:

```
 <script id="tpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="test">
                <h2>
                    Переменная равна: ${title}
                </h2>
        </div>
    </script>

    <div id="test1"></div>
```

JS:

```
       $(function () {
        $("#tpl").tmpl({ "title" : "Hello World" }).appendTo('#test1');
    });
```

Я не хотел бы в HTML коде страницы иметь шаблоны `text/x-jquery-tmpl` . Поэтому я перенес шаблонную часть в JS код:

```
 $(function () {
        $("<div class="test"><h2>Переменная равна: ${title}</h2></div>").tmpl({ "title" : "Hello World" }).appendTo('#test1');
    });
```

Но возникает ошибка!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так и как можно перенести шаблон из HTML в JavaScript код.

Спасибо!

Comment: "Но возникает ошибка!" - коллега, приоткройте завесу тайны - какая ошибка?

Comment: @igor пишет "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". Может быть это из-за двойных кавычек?

Comment: @Igor да, тупанул немного, надо было просто экранировать кавычки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $("<div class="test"><h2>Переменная равна: ${title}</h2></div>").tmpl({ "title" : "Hello World" }).appendTo('#test1');
> ```

Кавычки `"` надо заменить на `'`, чтобы двойные внутри строки не приходилось экранировать:

```
$('<div class="test"><h2>Переменная равна: ${title}</h2></div>').tmpl({ "title" : "Hello World" }).appendTo('#test1');
```

Но вообще код подозрительный - сначала формируем dom-дерево с шаблонами, а потом отдаём его шаблонизатору - не для этого шаблонизаторы придумывали, ты что-то делаешь не так.